# Closing a popup box in Google Translate

Tags: xpath, popup, css-selectors, nunit

I am new to NUNIT and am stumped on how to close a dialog box.

The site I am experimenting with is Google Translate.  Part of the code "clicks" on the "Send Feedback Link".

Below is the function I am using:

```
public void CloseModalWindow(string className)
{
    WebController wPage = new WebController(driver);
    wPage.waitUntilExistsByXPath(className);
    wPage.waitUntilVisibleByXPath(className);
    IWebElement clickButtonXPATH = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(className));
    clickButtonXPATH.Click();
}
```

The basic logic is that I am trying to simulate is to click the "X" on the upper right hand side of the Google Feedback popup that appears.

Please note that:

- The web driver is FireFox.
- I am sending the XPath value (derived from Google Translate directly using FireBug) `/html/body/div[3]/div/span[2]`.
- I've also tried using the CSSSelector method instead of XPATH, sending the value `span[class='modal-dialog-title']` into the function.

Nunit will in complete without any errors, but the popup does not close as I am anticipating.

Thank you in advance for your input and insight.

Comment: I don't know if i get you right. But if you would like to simulate a box window that could easably be closed check out FancyBox from JQuerry. Easy and looks neat. You could implement that in your HTML page with some simple script.

Comment: Kristoffer, thank you for your response.  I am actually trying to close a dialog box programmatically during an NUNIT session.

Answer (score 0):

From your XPath I see that the **"X"** is not a natively clickable element - like `<a>` or `<button>` are. I experienced that calling `Click()` on such elements does not what one expects. Instead you could try using the [action builder](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) functionality which will simulate a general mouse or keyboard input. Replace

```
clickButtonXPATH.Click();
```

with

```
new Actions(driver).Click(clickButtonXPATH).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Dio, thank you for the response and making me aware of the action builder class in Selenium.  I will look into the class in greater detail.  I have tried multiple variations and am still not able to close the popup box.  I've tried your code above (slightly modified by instantiating Actions into a an object called builder) , along with attempting to use builder.MoveToElement.(clickButtonXPATH).click().build().perform();. Do you have any other suggestions?  Thank you again.

Comment: Unfortunately not. That's all for now.